# How to check the source of analysis task in Oracle Performance Analyzer?

Tags: oracle, query-performance, performance-tuning, plsql, oracle-19c

We have provided sql tuning set as input to the analysis task of performance analyzer

```
variable l_task_id VARCHAR2(64);

exec :l_task_id:=dbms_sqlpa.create_analysis_task(
     sqlset_name => '<sql set name>'
    , sqlset_owner=>'<owner>'
    ,task_name => '<new task name>');
```

Now i want to list all the tasks associated with the sql tuning set. I have tried below ways but they are not working

```
select parameter_name,parameter_value 
from dba_advisor_exec_parameters 
where task_name='<task name>' and parameter_name='SQLSET_NAME';
```

But the result is showing "NOT USED" for column parameter_value

| parameter_name | parameter_value |
| --- | --- |
| SQLSET_NAME UNUSED |  |

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to know which sqlset is associated with the particular task exectution is to see the report (but this can be done only after task execution complete)

```
SELECT DBMS_SQLPA.REPORT_ANALYSIS_TASK(
    task_name => 'JRI1970_CCP66_OENV_02_T1'
    ,execution_name=> 'EXEC_255555') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

or try below:

```
select * from DBA_SQLSET_REFERENCES where sqlset_name ='XXXXX';
```

Comment: Instead of adding multiple answers, simple edit your existing answer and add the new details.  If you feel you need to provide two distinct answers, then ensure both answers can stand on their own merits, and have enough details to completely answer the question at hand.